# VS code intellisense doesn't work with numpy

Tags: numpy, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I usually use venv in my projects. Created by:
`python -m venv venv`

Most of my projects include numpy, so naturally I install that via pip too.

If I start VS code now, it analyses everything, its interpreter is the venv, and intellisense works fine.
[Intellisense working normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zye5p.png)

Now, if reboot my machine, or just re open the project at a later time, this is what I get for intellisense:

[Intellisense not working properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFfyG.png)

Can someone help me solve this? Thanks